# Scala wrappers for any of Java statistics libraries

Tags: java, scala, statistics

Does anybody know of a Scala wrapper for one of libraries mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448643/statistical-library-for-java or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86500/what-is-the-best-java-numerical-method-package?

Comment: Why do you need one? In particular, why is using the library as is not enough?

Comment: I don't _need_ one. But if one already exists, it could be used from Scala more idiomatically and save a bit of effort. This could be a useful factor in choosing which library to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at Scalala ( https://github.com/scalala/Scalala ) ? I don't know what your requirements regarding statically processing are, but this would provide you with vector and matrix algebra and plotting facilities.

Comment: I can use plotting, at least. I'll check if it does other things I need, as well.